# ImagePickerController crash presentViewController when called in UIStoryboardPopoverSegue

Tags: objective-c, crash, uiimagepickercontroller, uistoryboard, dismiss

I have a viewcontroller called via UIStoryboardPopoverSegue  and inside there is a button to call the imagePickerController, it's ok for the first call but the second time it crash.

The code is use is ok when it is not through UIStoryboardPopoverSegue.

```
   -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (image, nil, nil , nil);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
-(IBAction)takephoto:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        self.imagePicker.delegate=self;
        self.imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!self.imagePicker)
    {
        self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    }
}
```

I enabled NSZobmbie to show any log that can help me tracing it.

> *** -[UIImagePickerController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to
>   deallocated instance 0x1eb3b700

Answer (score 1):

Your UIImagePickerController is released and then attempted to be accessed later - so crashes!

To fix it, make the UIImagePickerController a strongly referenced property of the owning instance:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
```

initialise it once:

```
if (!self.imagePicker) self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

and use:

```
[self.imagePicker doStuff]
```

for access.

That should solve it.

**EDIT**

```
if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"tcwindshield"]) { 
   self.ips = [segue destinationViewController]; 
   self.ips.delegate = self
   self.ips.strStatValue=@"WindShield"; 
}
```

Comment: thank you  @Adam for the reply, apology if I'm confused with your instruction please check my revised code because it still crashes.
` if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            
            if (!self.imagePicker) self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            [self.imagePicker delegate];
            self.imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
`

Comment: self.imagePicker.delegate = self;

Comment: I'm still getting the crash issue  *** -[UIImagePickerController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1fd317c0 :(

Comment: thanks Adam for your time for this i really need help and the bug is very strange. I updated the code now, what i understood with initialize it once is i placed if `(!self.imagePicker) self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];` under viewDidLoad.

Comment: Have you added an exception breakpoint? That might show you were the program crashes. http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions.

Comment: Is the viewcontroller called via UIStoryboardPopoverSegue a strong property? Maybe that's released?

Comment: I added the exception breakpoint [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByavDvkVnkwgYVQwbkVJWHF5SUE/edit?usp=sharing) 
'@property (nonatomic, strong)InspectionPopStatViewController *ips;' 

'if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"tcwindshield"]) {
        ipspop=(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
        ips=[segue destinationViewController];
        [ips setDelegates:self];
        ips.strStatValue=@"WindShield";'
        
    }'

Comment: you need to do self.ipspop when you want to use your property. That's your issue.

Comment: i'm still getting the crash and its the same error message.:( 

`if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"tcwindshield"]) {
       ipspop=(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
        self.ips=[segue destinationViewController];
        self.ips.delegates=self;
        self.ips.strStatValue=@"WindShield";
    }`